# Facebook AppCenter for Native app - Screenshots won't update

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad

We have a native iOS app that uses Facebook for authenticating users.

So we are setting up the AppCenter for this app, but the screenshots won't upload.

So before hitting save:

[image: Before Pic]

After hitting save:

[image: Top]

[image: After Pic]

Has anyone gotten this to work lately?  The page seems broken.  We have waited 30 minutes and checked again, and tried several times with no luck.

It really sucks because if we try to submit the app for review:

[image: Error on Submit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after waiting approximately 3 hours.  All my screenshots showed up.

I guess patience is a virtue.